# Bootstrap carousel does fade but not slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

the items inside my bootstrap Carousel do not slide, just fade. That's not nice! :)

Thats my basic HTML I have:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I added meanwhile the complete bootstrap to my page with hope not to miss any component of bootstrap.

All other bootstrap things on my page are working nicely.

What can I check else?

Comment: Have you tested in multiple browsers ? only time I've seen that type behavior is when I am in IE7 / 8. And you're missing this class from your opening tag `data-ride="carousel"` it tells the carousel to start it's animation once the page has loaded.

Comment: data-attribute and browser-change doesn't help.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle so I can take a look at it?